# K&R book states using assignment operator will only compute the expression once?

Tags: c

I am reading K&R The C Programming Language, and in Chapter 2.10 it states:

> "If expr1 and expr2 are expressions, then
>
> ```
> expr1 op= expr2
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> expr1 = (expr1) op (expr2)
> ```
>
> except that expr1 is computed only once."

`op=` is referring to the binary operators you can use with assignment like `+=`, `-=` etc. (and in the 2nd line op just means a binary operator like `+`)

My first minor confusion is that `expr1` must be only a variable (an "lvalue")? Or else how can we assign a result to a larger expression? But my main question is what is meant by "`expr1` is computed only once"? Would something have been computed twice if we wrote:

```
expr1 = (expr1) op (expr2)
```

instead of

```
expr1 op= expr2
```

Comment: There are probably simpler examples, but consider the case where `f()` returns an `int *`.  Then in  `*f() += 1`,  `f` is only called once.

Comment: The K&R book is not representative of modern C.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understand now. Even though expr1 must be an assignment, there could be an expression somewhere inside the argument to an array or something. And then it's only called once, because it doesn't appear twice anymore. I think i'll close the question.

Comment: @Dai any other textbook you would recommend? It's not bad for getting the basics in.

Comment: @Azimuth https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Dai yeah but which one do you like? :)

Comment: @Azimuth At risk of being a hypocrite: I cut my teeth on the K&R C book too, but that was before _modern C_ became a thing. If I was learning C today I'd go with one of the books from that page, though leaning towards books from reputable technical publishers (e.g. Addison-Wesley or O'Reilly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feels contrived, but consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 0;

int *f(void) { printf("f is called\n"); return &x; }

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf(" x = %d\n", x);
    *f() += 1;  /* Calls f once */
    printf(" x = %d\n", x);
    *f() = *f() + 1;  /* Calls f twice */
    printf(" x = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

A less contrived example would be something like:

```
a[i++] += 1;
```

Comment: On this line: `*f() += 1;  /* Calls f once */` - while `f` is only invoked once, won't the returned `int*` be dereferenced at least twice?

Comment: @William Pursell thank you William for taking the time to answer! A function is a good example of something you might only want called once.

Comment: @Dai That's no different from directly modifying a variable that happens to be kept in memory. `*f()` is an lvalue, just as `x` is in `x += 1`, where the value stored in `x` is both read and written.